# Loading a DataTable with the items in a DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I do this in C#?, to pass the data from data set to a Data Table?

Comment: The .NET DataSet is a collection of DataTables and the data is contained within the DataTable and its entities (rows and columns). What do you need to do exactly?

Comment: Ok, what if my data set has 4 columns?, how can i pass the data set to a datatable?

Comment: Datasets do not have columns. Use standard terminology.

Comment: sorry, this is why I asked, I am new to c# and wanted to understand it now i know. I am sorry I am not as knowledgable as you HENK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DataSet is a collection of Tables, so

```
DataTable dt = dataSetInstance.Tables[0];
```

Comment: so if my sql table is passing 4 columns to the dataset the dataset table has 4 columns as well?

Comment: Yes.  If you're just doing something normal like calling a database and getting a dataset back, accessing the first table is your result set.

Comment: Great Thank you for your help! learning something new everytday :)

Answer (score 1):

A DataSet is like an in-memory database whereas a DataTable is an in-memory table.  So there could be multiple DataTable objects in your DataSet.  If you simply want to copy a DataTable from your DataSet to a DataTable you can do something like this:

```
myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0].Copy();
```

That is of course if the table you want in your DataSet is the first one.